# Country selection for a web form?

Tags: php, html

How to create a `HTML` **dropdown** with list of countries , is there any web services which i can use ? without entering manual.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: It'll probably take less time to go and copy and paste the country names now than get an answer here and implement the web service.

Comment: Java has a built in method for obtaining all countries: [Locale.getISOCountries()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISOCountries()). Unfortunately, there is no analog in PHP. Sorry.

Comment: @BoltClock - very shameful answer as a senior member !

Comment: @Sudantha: Which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Sudantha: @BoltClock is correct. Why taking extra pain to check whether the web service is everytime your dropdown is up and then falling back to your local resource? Its better to keep the list of countries codes and currencies in an xml or json and copy them for all your projects.

Comment: cool but i used the jquery extension . looks better .. also * hard-coding* looks not reliable when its long term ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this jQuery plugin:
[JQuery Autocomplete Plugin extension for country list](http://www.devtaxi.com/tools/accountry/)

Answer (score 1):

Get an array of country names [like this one](http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/list-country-codes-and-names-php-array-key-code-and-value-name-english).

Then use this in your file:

```
<select name="countries">
<?php
$countries = array(
    'AF'=>'AFGHANISTAN',
    'AL'=>'ALBANIA',
    'DZ'=>'ALGERIA',
    'AS'=>'AMERICAN SAMOA',
    ...rest of data from site link above
);
foreach($countries as $key => $array) {
    ?><option value="<?=$key?>"><?=$value?></option>
}
</select>
?>
```

**Explanation:**
Creates a array of country names, then goes through one at a time and writes each country name into an `<option>` within your `<select></select>` tags.